# how can I pass a list of dictionaries as function parameter?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, parameters

I have a list that contains a dictionary. 
A sample of mylist:

`products = [{u'title': u'product_A', u'int': [{u'content': 8112, u'name': u'orbitnumber'}, {u'content': 107, u'name': u'relativeorbitnumber'}], u'double': {u'content': 23.4161, u'name': u'cloudcoverpercentage'}]`

If I want to find specific items I use a 'for loop'.
for example:

```
for i in range(len(products)):
        unzip(products[i]["title"])
```

This piece of code works fine. 
Now, I want to pass that list to a fresh function as a parameter.

How can I define that function that can take 'products' list as argument ? I know that in python you can pass a list as parameter with: *args. But how can I define for example products[list_index]["key"] in a general way in a function.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: You can pass any object as a parameter to a python function. if your code returns a list you can just pass it as def myfunc_that_parses_list(some_object_that_just_happens_to_be_a_list) The *args and **args notation is used when you don't know how many parameters your input to the function has. Which is not really your case, you know your function only needs a list as input. More details on use of args notation : https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Answer (score 2):

Example your function is my_f
You can define it as follow:

```
def my_f(my_var):
    # then you can do anything you want
    my_var[list_index]["key"] = "0123"
    # Do some other works
    # ...
    # You can return my_var if you need the above change
    return my_var
```

At other place where you call my_f function and pass "products" as a parameter of my_f function

```
new_list = my_f(products)
```

It is just one case to pass parameters.
Note that in python you can pass anything as a parameter

Comment: If you define a function with two parameters as input without defaulting the second to a value and pass only one parameter to it when you call it, you'll get a TypeError for "Missing required positional argument".

Comment: Thank you for your answer  @Toandd! It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Toandd.
Another way to do it is:
1. define a dictionary with the params you would like to change or include in your dictionary

```
dictionary = dict(key1=value1,key2=value2)
```

2. Pass the dictionary to your function

`dictionary_treatment = your_function(dictionary)`

It works for me!

Regards